# Can not catch assert call from native dll in .NET

Tags: .net, dll, unmanaged, assert

I am using one function from native .dll in C# code and sometimes the following assert is calling:

```
#include <assert.h>
...
assert(e > 0.0);
```

But I can not catch it in my .NET application (it's just crashing). How can I handle this?

Comment: You can't. Make sure that you're calling the code correctly instead of relying on exceptions. This is exactly what asserts are for.

Comment: It's *meant* to crash/abort. The fix is to not pass a (combination of) inputs to the function such that they violate the necessary preconditions for the function, including this one.

Comment: You need to stay a mile away from code that is so unreliable that the author doesn't trust it enough to give you the Release build.  Or you'd better establish a good working relationship with him, it is going to take a while to get the bugs out.  Most important thing for you to do is to give him small repro projects so he can fix his bugs.

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you. I wrote to the author of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least by reading the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h):

> When executed, if the expression is false (that is, compares equal to 0), assert() writes information about the call that failed on stderr and then **calls abort()**.

And the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9sb57dw4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Evaluates an expression and, when the result is false, prints a diagnostic message and **aborts the program**.

so no exception... an error message and the program dies. Nothing to catch here :-)

Then we could talk about the difference in parameters handling between C and C#... In C you kill the program with an `assert`, in C# you throw a catcheable exception (`ArgumentException`)... Different methodologies :-)

Now, how to handle it? Don't cause `assert` to fail is a good method :-) `assert` are terminal errors (because even in C they can't be handled), so they shouldn't happen.